# How to pick up the numbers in URL?

Tags: java

This is part of URL :

```
String str = "/item/board_read.nhn?code=008250&nid=22939649&st=&sw=&page=1";
```

I want to pick up the attribute of **nid**, `22939649` . How can I do that?
I tried it using Jsoup parser.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(str);
String nid = doc.attr(nid);
System.out.println(nid);
```

But I can't see anything. maybe that way just pick up HTML attr, not a general string. Should I use regx?

Comment: is this link passed after a request? are you using servlet?

Comment: why just not use indexOf ? find nid then find & and copy whatever in between ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with using [`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29)?

```
String number = str.substring(str.indexOf("nid=") + 4, str.indexOf("&st="));
```

Comment: why  you have added +4 to the first parameter ?

Comment: What's wrong: query parameter order is virtually never relevant. 1) It will fail if the order is different 2) It will also fail if `st` is omitted 3) It will fail if another parameter containing the sequence `nid` is present before the `nid` parameter. It works in this case but only if the url format will never change.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple regexp or recreate a query parser.
Remove part before "?" with indexof.
Split with &
Foreach, split with = to have code and value.

Can you give us the context to let you find the classe that already implemented your need.
Is it in webapp? or.. ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Apache's [`URLEncodedUtils`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html)

```
List<NameValuePair> params = URLEncodedUtils.parse(URI.create(str), "UTF-8");
for (NameValuePair param : params) {
    if (param.getName().equals("nid")) {
        System.out.println(param.getValue());
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could just keep it real simple

```
String str = "/item/board_read.nhn?code=008250&nid=22939649&st=&sw=&page=1";
int startIndex = str.indexOf("nid=");
int endIndex = str.indexOf('&', startIndex);
String nid = str.substring(startIndex+4, endIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

Jsoup parser is no help here.

You can use regex:

```
  //String str = "/item/board_read.nhn?nid=22939649&code=008250&st=&sw=&page=1";
  //String str = "/item/board_read.nhn?code=008250&st=&sw=&page=1&nid=22939649";
  String str = "/item/board_read.nhn?code=008250&nid=22939649&st=&sw=&page=1";

  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[?&]nid=(\\d+)");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
  if (m.find()) {
    String nid = m.group(1);
    System.out.println(nid);
  }
  else {
    System.out.println("nid not found");
  }
```

This works with any parameters in any order inside the URL.